# Some spaces after the linebreak in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a long string that have to be represent in the TextView using bullets. But after each line i could not make some spaces.

What i got was:
* The text was .............. .......................... .............       ............. ................ .................. .................         .................... ........................... 
.............................................................................

*Another line................................................. .................         .................... ........................... .............................................................................

*Another line................................................. .................         .................... ........................... .................................................................................................................


**What i want is,**

- The text was .............. .......................... .............                ............. ................ .................. .................         .................... ........................... 
  .............................................................................
- Another line................................................. .................         .................... ........................... .............................................................................
- Another line................................................. .................         .................... ........................... .................................................................................................................

  **After the bullets there should be proper indentation and should use single text view.**

Comment: Post your code then we can help..

Comment: Post your code.....................

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get bullet span string :

```
public static CharSequence makeBulletList(int leadingMargin, CharSequence... lines) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            CharSequence line = lines[i] + (i < lines.length-1 ? "\n" : "");
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(line);
            spannable.setSpan(new BulletSpan(leadingMargin), 0, spannable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            sb.append(spannable);
        }
        return sb;
    }
```

You can also modify this method to take an array list as input.